# MYSQL combine multiple rows into single row using join with another table

Tags: mysql

I want to join a table with another table but i need multiple row values from second table.

Table #1:(orders)

```
userid  order_id

1412    1412_AD_150910
1413    1413_AD_150910
```

Table #2:(follow_up)

```
userid date    comments        called

1412   150910   test comments    1
1412   150911   comments1        0
1413   150912   test             1
```

Results will be like this:

```
userid  order_id         follow_up_details

1412    1412_AD_150910   [{150910,testcomments,1},{150911,comments1,0}]
1413    1413_AD_150910   [{150912,test,1}]
```

Basically i want to combine rows from second table using userid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you want something like a `JSON`, right? Then you could use a combination of [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to achieve your goal.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  t1.userid,
  t2.order_id,
  CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{',t2.date,',',t2.comments,',',t2.called,'}')),']') AS follow_up_details
FROM
  table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
GROUP BY
  t1.userid;
```

---

**P.S.:** This kind of string formatting is better done on your application (on your PHP code for example), as if those tables have many entries, your query will get very slow.

**P.S.2:** From the docs:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024.

You can change that by running the following code before your `SELECT`.

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4096;
```

Of course, set any value you like instead of `4096`.

The syntax is:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Answer (score 2):

These type string formatting should be done on the application level in general. However if there is a constraint that it needs to be done on DB level you can do as

```
select
o.userid,
o.order_id,
concat('[',group_concat(concat('{',f.date,',',f.comments,',',f.called,'}')),']') as follow_up_details
from orders o 
join follow_up f on f.userid = o.userid
group by o.userid
```